# Can I customize the "You have new mail" message

Tags: bash, ssh, email, motd

I'm trying to modify the `You have new mail` message that is shown below MOTD when you login via SSH.
My goal is to make that message more visible (bright color would be great) so it gets my attention when I log in.

Comment: I took a quick look at Bash source code and it seems it's not possible to customize. The message is hardcoded in `mailcheck.c.`. But you can always recompile Bash.

Comment: @ArkadiuszDrabczyk look harder

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In Bash, custom messages can be set with MAILPATH. The man page has this example:

```
MAILPATH='/var/mail/bfox?"You have mail":~/shell-mail?"$_ has mail!"'
```

Trying it:

```
$ export MAILPATH="$MAIL?\"Santa was here.\""
$
$
$
$ 
"Santa was here."
```

Oh, uh, okay. Must have misread the man page there.

> bright color would be great

So we have to smuggle us some [color escape codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code#Colors) into the message...

```
$ esc=$'\e'
$ export MAILPATH="$MAIL?$esc[1;37;44mREAD YOUR MAIL RIGHT NOW$esc[0m"
$ echo $MAILPATH
/var/spool/mail/frostschutz?READ YOUR MAIL RIGHT NOW
$
$
READ YOUR MAIL RIGHT NOW
```

I don't know how to color things here, just imagine it screaming in bright white blue. Color choices are subject to taste and local terminal color scheme settings.

Also check that MAILPATH was not already in use and MAIL actually has the correct path to use for MAILPATH.

Answer (score 0):

I think the text you are asking about is the text generated by the [libpam module pam_mail](https://linux.die.net/man/8/pam_mail). There is no way to customize the text that is output.

I recently filed [a bug about some text changes to the module](https://github.com/linux-pam/linux-pam/issues/465) that make it less easy to see at a glance that you have mail, and while looking for a solution I could do myself I discovered that there are no ENV vars or anything to customize that text. That would be a great solution to the bug I filed though.

Also, FWIW, the `$MAIL` env var is a configurable option in the module, and by default it is turned off in Ubuntu in the `/etc/pam.d/sshd` file via the `noenv` option:

```
# Print the status of the user's mailbox upon successful login.
session    optional     pam_mail.so standard noenv # [1]
```